# Can you calculate the coefficient of inbreeding (F) without a family history?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics

Apologies in advance, this question may be completely obvious.

Say, I didn't have a family tree for two individuals. Could I calculate their coefficient of inbreeding? If not, is there a good proxy for it or an alternative way to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

These days inbreeding coefficients are generally computed from observed gene frequencies, not from pedigrees.

From [this review](https://www.nature.com/articles/6800065.pdf):

> Inbreeding coefficients are defined in terms of the
> probability of identity in state of different pairs of genes.
> Here the probability of identity in state is simply the
> probability that two genes are of identical allelic type.

Comment: Thank you very much. One further question. How expensive would it be to calculate the coefficient of inbreeding for a random couple? I'm an Economist and this isn't my domain of expertise.

Comment: @anonymousquestionbio1994 It really depends on the degree of precision that you want, density of information, extensibility, etc. I suggest doing some background reading on the topic of experimental design in the field: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2020.00870/full, https://apsjournals.apsnet.org/doi/pdf/10.1094/PHYTO-12-16-0425-RVW

Comment: Thank you again! Will certainly be reading this!